# Minecraft won't run. Multiple items cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: typeerror, minecraft

I just finished skating around that infamous "cannot load main class start" thing, and I got blindsided with a sea of errors:

[image: Look at all these mother****ers]

A friend suggests it might have something to do with com.google, but ultimately can't help me.

I haven't made a single alteration to any of the code so far. Eclipse just started up not being able to run and stayed that way. I think there's a way to fix it but it would require making acute changes at the sight of every single error; work that could be wiped by a cleanup if I'm proved wrong.

Anyone have a clue what the issue is? Thank you for the trouble.

UPDATE: Adding guava as a library relieved the error involving com.google, but threw in a handful of others. This one class file contains 3 of the most common unresolved types I've seen scattered throughout: Logger/LogManagaer, PropertyMap, and CrashReport

[image: The fact that Minecraft is squiggled is also worrisome.]

Comment: @DylanCorriveau Do you at least spent 5 seconds on actually watching provided screen-shot, before saying anything? OP asks about programmig problem and provides screenshot of code. This has **nothing** to do with arcade.SE!

Comment: Could you, instead of a screenshot, copy the bare text?

Comment: I don't think it's the code that's the problem as I haven't made any alterations, but I'll transcribe the second screenshot just in case.

Comment: @bigbrain446 is correct. The code is not the issue, although posting plain text helps readability. The fundamental issue is that you are not able to understand the compilation errors that Eclipse / the compiler is giving you. However, you need to be able to understand them in order to continue. You have enough info in the answers below to continue, and at this point you must be willing to put some effort in. Constructively, but to be blunt, these are very basic errors; if you cannot or will not take effort to resolve them with the given information, you will have trouble proceeding in general.

Answer (score 1):

Your general problems revolve around not having dependencies in the build path. Eclipse's error messages are pretty clear about this; e.g. if a package name is underlined in red and can't be found, then that means it can't be found, and the obvious solution is to add the library that provides it, so that it can be found.

In virtually all cases here, a Google search for the missing packages and classes will lead you to the packages that contain it.

For each unresolved dependency, find the library, add it to the build path, then move on.

I also suggest consulting the documentation that comes with the source code you are attempting to compile, which often simply lists the dependencies, thus saving you the trouble of hunting them down as you go.

While we could do the internet searches for you and hash this out one step at a time, it's both better and faster for you to do it yourself. Better because if you're messing around with Minecraft source, *having at least a basic knowledge of how your tools work is going to help you* (I also suggest some of the material at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/). Faster because the turnaround time of typing package names into the Google search box is a heck of a lot faster than constantly updating your question here and waiting for replies.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't mean to request that you search for things for me, but I thought there might be some other pack similar to guava that someone could recommend. As you mentioned, I have very minimal understanding of all this. I'll reread all the included documents and try google searching all the errors again, as I was sure to do before asking the question. Sorry to make you feel as though you've wasted your time.

Comment: To be clear, I do not feel as if I've wasted my time. My point is that addressing the fundamental issue rather than its consequences one by one gives you the tools you need to solve these problems quickly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the Google Collections package, which now is called [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).

Download the jar file, and add it as a library.

Comment: Thank you for the Guava link. I've placed the jar in my referenced libraries, but all the same errors are still present. Is it possible I imported it incorrectly?

Comment: I'm not sure if a referenced library is the same as putting it in the Java Build Path as a Library: http://i.stack.imgur.com/A6xgq.png

Comment: I'm not entirely sure either, but my libraries folder definitely matches your screenshot.